# How do I interpret this this confusingly worded prompt?

Tags: calculus, functions

Use transformation of $f(x) = x^2$ to graph the following function:

$$g(x)=(x+5)^2+3$$

Use the graphing tool to graph the function.

So they provide a little tool for drawing the graph. At first I though I just square $g(x)$ and then graph it, but there's not enough room for the values in the graph space provided, leading me to think I took the wrong approach. How is this supposed to be solved?

Comment: They want you to use the graph of $f(x)$ to graph $g(x)$. How are they related?

Comment: @pwerth i honestly have no idea. It seems so basic and simple, but the instructions are unclear. I was thinking maybe plug g(x) into f(x), but the smallest y results are out of the range of the blank graph they gave us for this problem

Comment: Consider the graph of any $f(x)$, not necessarily the one in this problem. What can you say about the graph of $f(x) + 3$ compared to graph of $f$? What can you say about the graph of $f(x+5)$ compared to the graph of $f$?

Comment: @pwerth up 3, left 5, then square?

Comment: Yes. So you can just graph $f(x) = x^{2}$, then move it up $3$ units and left $5$ units and that will be the graph of $g$.

Comment: @pwerth great, that worked, thanks